Does this picture indicate why my light switch doesn't work?
Possible crazy question:This is a light switch in my home and it rarely works. For 5-10 years now I have to jiggle the switch to get the light to turn on but there's never an issue when I flick the switch to turn the light off. Another issue is that the light never turns on during the summertime or when it's warm outside. I have to basically wait until the Winter and then the light will turn on. I don't know anything about wiring or electricity so can anyone tell me if they can identify what's causing these issues from this picture?


Call an electrician. Even if we can diagnose it, you haven't instilled much confidence that you'd be able to fix it.

No.  Well, maybe.  We can't see anything in the photo except that the switch is old.  The age may be why it's flaky.  There's a good chance simply replacing it will fix your problem.

That's all the classic symptoms of a loose or faulty connection at the switch
You've got a loose or bad connection at the switch in question -- it's only sometimes making contact, more often when cold than when warm, which explains why it sometimes works when you jiggle the switch.

The photos are not showing anything unusual.
Unless you want to start studying electrical repair books, your other options are to find a friend or electrician with more experience about this.
The switch likely needs to be replaced.  If the switching function can't be confirmed with a simple voltage test then a good troubleshooting technique is to turn off the circuit breaker, totally disconnect the switch, and check its function with a continuity tester.  At that point, the switch is easily replaced anyway.  If the old switch was still functional then the connections and other parts of the circuit can be checked too.
